# How to split an EDIFACT file?

Tags: oracle, split, soa, b2b, edifact

I'm using the Oracle SOA Suite B2B component to process an EDIFACT file. I need to process a +2Gb file and it can't be process all at once. I need to split the file into smaller ones and then process them all. Is there any Java application that help me with this splitting problem?? ..

Or if I try to develop it, How should be the format of the smaller EDIFACT files in order to be able to preocess them?..

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`EDIFACT` interchange files are composed of segments. Each segment ends with a segment delimiter. Therefore, it would be quite easy to write a small program to split your file into two or more smaller parts. Note that the segment delimiter can be chosen in the first segment (`UNA`).

However, this splitting will affect the overall structure of your `EDIFACT` file. It takes deaper knowledge of the interchange/message structure to find a viable split location.

The overall structure of an `EDIFACT` interchange looks as [follows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDIFACT):

```
        Service String Advice     UNA  Optional
 +----- Interchange Header        UNB  Mandatory
 | +---   Functional Group Header   UNG  Conditional
 | | +-     Message Header            UNH  Mandatory
 | | |        User Data Segments             As required
 | | +-     Message Trailer           UNT  Mandatory
 | +---   Functional Group Trailer  UNE  Conditional
 +----- Interchange Trailer       UNZ  Mandatory
```

If your big file contains many messages (starting with `UNH` and ending with `UNT` segments), you could split along the message boundaries and add artifical `UNB/UNZ` envelopes.